# SPARQL getting an intersecting set

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

I following data:

```
:A :hasCity City1
:A :hasCity City2
:A :hasCity City3
:A :hasCity City4

:K :hasCity City1
:K :hasCity City2
```

......

I'm trying to find all subjects that have cities 1 and 2 so I wrote the query:

```
select ?s 
{
   ?s :hasCity ?city.
   FILTER (?city =:City1 && ?city=:City2)
}
```

But, I don't get back any results.

if I just do:

```
select ?s 
{
   ?s :hasCity ?city.
   FILTER (?city =:City1)
}
```

I get back A,K,Q,M and if I just do:

```
select ?s 
{
   ?s :hasCity ?city.
   FILTER (?city =:City2)
}
```

I get back A,K,L

so when I use the  && operator, I should get back A&K, right? Am I missing something?

Comment: "so when I use the && operator, I should get back A&K, right?" - no that says 'get a city value, where the value is both 1 and 2'. Hence no results.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure I understand it. Going by what you say, A&K have a City value of 1&2 so they should be returned, right?

Comment: No, ?city is *either* City1 *or* City2. So the filter always fails. It might help to think about what the filter operates on: the pattern `?s :hasCity ?city` results in a series of bindings <A, 1>, <A, 2>, ... <K, 2>. The filter keeps bindings where the second value is 1 *and* 2 - which never happens. Does that help?

Comment: Hmmmm.... some reason I still can't seem to follow. Perhaps if you give me an example where && does work, I might be able to see the contrast. Because everything you've said so far and the example on the sparql w3 page all seems to point to it working for my example.

Comment: ?s = :A && ?city = :City1 would find something

Comment: Looks like it finally is making sense to me. Looks like the && operator checks within **one triple** and not across triples. So, in that case having a && operator between the same variable (?a=something and ?a= someOtherThing) would never return a result, right?

Comment: Within one *binding*. So, for example, if you searched for `?s :hasCity ?c1 . ?s :hasCity ?c2 .` `FILTER (?c1 =:City1 && ?c2=:City2)` would do what you expect. (As the answer below shows, there's a simpler way to write that)

Comment: I think I've parsed it well, finally. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is ask for all subjects that share the same set of objects, using a triple pattern on the same property. You'd end up with a very simple query:

```
SELECT ?s {?s :hasCity :City1, :City2}
```

With `:hasSubject`, if you want to keep the one-line query, you just ask for the inverse of the property:

```
SELECT ?s { ?s ^:hasSubject :City1, :City2}
```

When using `=` , you need to ensure you compare apples with apples. For example `?a = ?b`, or `str(?a) = str(<b>)`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I just realized that the predicate has the reverse direction. Its actually:

`:City1 :hasSubject :A`. What can I do then?

Also, why would you say the '&&' not working?

Comment: Helpful indeed. Would be super if you could also shed light on why the && is not working the same way.